# How do I access Option types stored in a Vec?

Tags: rust

I am having trouble with this simple construct:

```
fn main() { 
    let mut stack: Vec<Option<&str>> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(None);
    let item: Option<&str> = stack.pop();
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
src/main.rs:4:30: 4:41 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::option::Option<&str>`,
    found `core::option::Option<core::option::Option<&str>>`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:4     let item: Option<&str> = stack.pop();
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:4:30: 4:41 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
```

How can I store `Option` types in a `Vec`, and access individual elements still wrapped in an `Option`?

Comment: `Vec.pop()` returns an `Option<T>` in case the vector is empty, so if `T` is `Option<&str>`, it should return _`Option<Option<&str>>`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized what's going on. `Vec` returns an `Option<T>`.